# How do I solve a function for a given x?

Tags: r, function

I have been browsing through quite some help pages, but I did not find the solution for my - probably - simple problem.
I defined a function

```
funB <- function(x) (0.8042851 + 
    ((3.9417843-0.8042851)/(1+((x/0.4039609)^(-3.285016)))))
```

and would like to solve it for a given x (say, x = 0.2).
How do I do that? I have looked at `uniroot()` and `polyroot()`, but they did not seem to fit my function.

Comment: can you please clarify?  @LenGreski's answer might be what you want, but somehow it seems too easy?

Comment: @BenBolker I believe the OP wants the value of `funB(x) == 0.2`.

Comment: that's what I suspected, but it's not what they said ...

Comment: @BenBolker - you're right, it all depends on what Crystal means by "solve".

Comment: You can plot your function using `plot(funB, to = 100, from = -100)`. Mathematically the function has a minimum of 0.8 in the reals for x = 0, so it is no surprise that there is no root or solution for funB(x) = 0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be sure that there is a root where you are expecting it, plot the graph of `funB`.

```
curve(funB)
```

Define an auxiliary function, `f`, taking an extra argument and solve this new function for `a = <target_value>`.

```
f <- function(x, a) funB(x) - a

uniroot(f, interval = c(0, 1e3), a = 2)

#$root
#[1] 0.3485097
#
#$f.root
#[1] -0.0001305644
#
#$iter
#[1] 12
#
#$init.it
#[1] NA
#
#$estim.prec
#[1] 6.103516e-05
```

Comment: works for target = 2 but fails for the requested value of target = 0.2 ...

Comment: @BenBolker That's true, it doesn't have a root there. The question is not very clear, I believe that `0.2` is just an example, not a very good one.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! When I formulated the question, x = 0.2 was meant as a random example, a bad one I saw now because it does not produce any results in this function.

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to find the value of `x` such that `funB(x)` was equal to 0.2, you would do something like this:

```
funB <- function(x) (0.8042851 + 
    ((3.9417843-0.8042851)/(1+((x/0.4039609)^(-3.285016))))) 
target <- 0.2
uniroot(function(x) funB(x)-target, interval=c(-5,10))
```

**but** there's a problem.  It's up to you to pick an `interval` value that brackets a root (i.e. `funB(x)<0.2` for the lower value and >0.2 for the upper value, or vice versa. `funB` is `NaN` for x<0, 0.8042851 for x==0, and increasing for x>0 (try `curve(funB, from=-5, to=100, n=1001)` for example).  So the solution you want (if I've guessed right about the meaning of your question) doesn't seem to exist.

**note**: in general a negative value raised to a negative power is `NaN` in R (even in cases where the answer "should" be defined, e.g. (-8)^(1/3) is the cube root of -8, which is -2 ...).  If you're sure you know what you're doing you could replace `(x/a)^b` with `sign(x)*(abs(x)/a)^b)` ... (if you make this change, the function appears well-behaved for x>-0.4 and `funB(x)-0.2` does have a root between -0.3 and -0.2 ... but *I have no idea if this makes sense for your application or not*)

Comment: ...or you could find the complex root, as per my (possibly tongue-in-cheek) answer

Comment: plus-one for explaining why the function is `NaN` for x < 0.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I guess I must like doing things the hard way. I just rearranged your function to find its inverse:

```
funC <- function(y) (((3.137499)/(y - 0.8042851) - 1)^(-1/3.285016)) * 0.4039609
```

So if I want to know when `funB(x) == 3.7` I can do:

```
funC(3.7)
#> [1] 0.860193
```

and sure enough

```
funB(0.860193)
#> [1] 3.7
```

or indeed

```
funB(funC(1))
#> [1] 1
```

And as others have pointed out, x doesn't have a real value at `funB(x) == 0.2` as you can see in this plot:

```
curve(funC, 0, 4)
```

[image]

Now, if you really want to know the complex root where `funB(x) == 0.2` then you can modify `funC` like so:

```
funC <- function(y) (((3.137499)/(as.complex(y) - 0.8042851) - 1)^(-1/3.285016)) * 0.4039609
```

So now:

```
funC(0.2)
#> [1] 0.1336917+0.1894797i
```

And therefore the answer to your question is **0.1336917 +/- 0.1894797i**

```
funB(complex(real = 0.133691691, imaginary = 0.1894797))
[1] 0.1999996+0i
```

Close enough.

Comment: plus-one for bringing imaginary numbers into the equation (pun intended).

Comment: That crossed my mind (not inverting the function analytically, but extending the problem to the complex domain): however, illustrating that for the cube root of -8 is a little inconvenient: `(-8+0i)^(1/3)` gives the "wrong" root (1+1.732051i, not -2);you have to go to `polyroot(c(-8,0,01))` to get all three roots, and that seemed too far down the rabbit hole ...

Comment: By the way, do you know if this is a unique solution ... ?

Comment: There are two roots @BenBolker - the imaginary is a + / - . I don't think there are any others. You can plot `funC` and have a look.

Answer (score 1):

```
funB <- function(x) (0.8042851 + ((3.9417843-0.8042851)/(1+((x/0.4039609)^(-3.285016)))))

# call the function with desired input
funB(0.2)
```

...and the output:

```
> funB(0.2)
[1] 1.087758
>
```